# Was V'ger (the Voyager 6 space probe) the beginning of the Borg collective in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

In Star Trek: The Motion Picture, an entity named V'ger shows up wreaking havoc in the Sol System.

Through some inquiry, investigation and risk taking, the Enterprise crew figures out that it is in fact NASA's Voyager space probe, which had met a machine race somewhere in deep space (possibly the Delta Quadrant).  This machine race repaired Voyager to the best of their ability, gave it a ship and sent it home to Earth.  Somewhere along the way, V'ger became self-aware and wanted to know its purpose.   In fact, it was willing and able to destroy anyone it met who couldn't tell it what its purpose was.

Captain Decker allows himself to be merged with V'ger (trying to get some of the Ilia probe chick at the same time), creating a new bio-mechanical entity, which satisfies V'ger's need for purpose.    They then vanish into what Spock assumes is another dimension (but could just as easily be transwarp back to the Delta Quadrant or elsewhere).

My question is this - does this mean that Captain Decker, by virtue of merging his biological distinctiveness with that of V'ger's technology and the technology added to V'ger by the machine race, become the very first Borg?  In essence, the first Borg King to the artificial "Ilia" as the Borg Queen?  And does Decker's ultimate morality cause the Borg Queen to then seek out Picard/Locutus and Data as replacement Borg Kings?  Clearly she was very motivated to find a companion in each mention instance.

If so, then in the prequel series Enterprise, when Archer and his crew are unable to destroy the shuttle modified by the Borg drones found in the arctic (the one presumably stranded in the ice during the events of Star Trek: First Contact)  before they could send their message to an unknown location deep in the Delta Quadrant - was that message ultimately the reason for V'gers return?   Or perhaps the reason for the machine race sending V'ger back?

In essence, did we create the Borg ourselves?

Comment: See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-was-the-origin-of-star-treks-borg

Answer (score 3):

No.

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg#History) the Borg were around centuries before humanity ever even made it close to space:

> As of 1484, they were reported as controlling only a handful of systems in the Delta Quadrant [...]

Comment: You think in such three dimensional terms.