# Who was the first Borg?

Tags: star-trek-voyager, borg

In 'Star Trek: Voyager', we find out in one of the episodes (I for the life of me can't remember which... edits are welcome), that the Borg Queen (portrayed beautifully by Susanna Thompson) comes from the species 129 (or was it 126?). That means, she definitely wasn't the first Borg, for then she would've called her species, "species 1" for the Borg do not use the Universal Standard Terminology (if there is even such a thing) and use their own system. So, who was the first Borg?

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-was-the-origin-of-star-treks-borg ?

Comment: @JonClements, Not exactly, but related. I was specifically asking about the first person to become a Borg (probably the one who first created the nano-probes?)

Comment: @JonClements I hadn't realised those books were so old. The first borg are created in the Destiny books, I don't think any TV or film versions have provided an alternate origin story.

Comment: 'then she would've called her species, "species 1"' — I don't think we know for sure that the Borg use sequential numbering for species.

Comment: If the books in the duplicate question count, then it sounds like there wasn't a "first" Borg; rather they evolved from another species.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, I would say it's probably based on encounter sequence... as in the sequence in which the species were encountered by the Borg (Although, that's another [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256991/on-what-basis-do-the-borg-number-the-species) entirely). Even in that case, they would call themselves Species 1 or Species 0 even (like unimatrix 0, you know?)